# Are FD_SET, FD_CLR ... atomic operations?

Tags: c, multithreading

The application I am currently working on is a server which will manage connection with the client using select(), each time the server receive a message, it will open a new thread in order to read the socket. During that time the file descriptor of the socket is remove from the set, and will be added at the end of the read.
Here is a sample of the code

```
struct s_handle {
 int sock;
 fd_set * rdfs;
};




int main(){
 ...
 fd_set rdfs;
 ...
 while(1){
 ....
  select(nb_fd,&rdfs,NULL,NULL,NULL)
  for_each(peer){
   if(FD_ISSET(peer->sock,&rdfs)){
     struct s_handle * h = malloc(sizeof(struct s_handle));
     h->sock = peer->sock;
     h->rdfs = &rdfs;
     FD_CLR(peer->sock,&rdfs);
     pthread_create(thread,NULL,handle,(void *)&h);
   }
  }
 ...
 }
 ...
 }

void* handle(void* argss){
 struct s_handle * temp = (struct s_handle *) argss;
 ...
 FD_SET(temp->sock,temp->rdfs);
}
```

Does FD_SET, FD_ISSET and FD_CLR are atomic operation, or do i need to lock rdfs with a mutex?

If a mutex is needed, how can I avoid deadlocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be creating threads like that. Creating a thread is a fairly high overhead operation and should only be used when you need more *threads*, not just because you have to do more work.

And yes, you do need to protect the `FD_*` functions with a mutex. The usual solution is to have a mutex that you hold only for the split second it takes to perform the `FD_*` operation. Before calling `select`, you acquire the mutex, make a copy of the descriptor set, and then release the mutex.

In general though, it's a bad idea to remove the socket from the read set. Putting the socket back in the read set won't change the `select` that's already occurring later on. And you'll have the ugly mess of figuring out how to get the thread calling `select` out of `select` in order to operate on the new set.

You may want to rethink your I/O discovery method and use one of the standard ones instead of trying to roll your own. You're forcing the ugly tradeoff of either having some sockets not being listened to for read because the were recently read and the `select` is still blocked or having to re-`select` as you finish reading from each socket. Neither solution is good.

A more common pattern is to keep the socket in the set while you're reading on it and not go back to `select` until all sockets have been read from (but not necessarily had their data processed).

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that they are, and you should not rely on it at all.

`fd_set`s are often implemented with plain bit-maps (arrays of `int`s or similar), and the `FD_*` macros are just bit-manipulation operations. Those operations are very rarely atomic on anything longer than the plateform-native `int` (if even for that).

Answer (score 1):

`FD_SET`, `FD_ISSET`, etc. are macros -- I don't think you can count on them being atomic.  However, rather than using a mutex, I'd suggest rethinking your approach; creating a new thread whenever you need to read, and calling `select` from a different thread than the one that uses its results both seem like bad ideas.  If there's a particular reason why you need to use a separate thread *just for the read* rather than to completely handle that connection, then why not let it have its own `fd_set` and call `select` itself?

---

Upon rereading the question, I'd say if you *do* use the approach you are now, you should note that your read `fd_set` needs to be rebuilt before each call to `select`, and is modified by the call.  So, the `FD_SET` at the end of the thread function isn't useful anyway, since the descriptor would be removed from the set on the next `select` call if it's not ready for reading again.  You need to build your read set in your `select` thread before the `select` call instead -- so you need an alternate means of determining which sockets need to be included.

You could add a busy flag to your `s_handle` struct, and guard *that* with a mutex -- you would then set it before you create the thread, and have the thread clear it when it exits.  When filling your read `fd_set` before the select call, you'd add the sockets for each peer that is not marked "busy" by the flag in the `s_handle` struct.

Comment: If you let that thread have its own `fd_set` and call `select` itself, then that thread has to stay around just to wait for I/O. Then no work could be done on that socket until that particular thread was scheduled. So you'll consume lots of extra resources will all these threads just sitting around waiting and you'll need tons of extra context switches to get the 'right' threads running. (But then, given that he's using `select`, he probably doesn't care about performance.)

Comment: I had things a little confused when writing that -- it didn't quite click that he was spawning a thread to read, then exiting it without repolling.  I was thinking more along the lines of creating a thread to read the socket, and keeping it around until the connection closes -- though it doesn't look like that's what he was doing.